# CSS image height auto causing incorrect aspect ratio

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Very strange issue I am running into here...

I have an image with dimensions: 570x400. I'm have this build responsive, so in order to scale the image down I am using:
img {max-width:100%; height:auto;}

This works great... however when I reach the max size, for some reason the image is being displayed at: 570x406. It's like improperly calculating the aspect ratio.

Here is the site i am working on:
http://www.juliancaustrita.com/

Has anyone encountered this before? I have built many sites using the "max-width 100%; height:auto" and have never seen this before....

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of the 10px white border you are applying to the `.img-frame`.

Comment: yup- realized that RIGHT after i posted... Will mark you correct once it allows me (said 8mins)

Comment: Set the ´border: 10px solid #fff` to `.slideshow figure` instead, and remove `width: 100%` from that element to achieve the desired effect.

Answer (score 1):

CSS widths include padding and borders. The class `.img-frame` which you've applied on the images give them a border of 10px.

This screenshot of Chrome's element inspector might make things clearer:

[image]